# Trying To change in technical stuff in macros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have this function in macros and I want to change it

```
if(SRS == "Gfycat:")
{
iimPlay(macro_spam)
var chk = 1
}
```

I want to change it so as it will work whatever the word is unlike the mentioned word above

Comment: If always want "iimPlay(macro_spam)" to be called then delete the if-clause. If that is your question.

Answer (score 0):

The operator you are looking for is `!==` which is not equal to, so the macro will run for all values except `Gfycat:`

```
if(SRS !== "Gfycat:") {
    iimPlay(macro_spam)
    var chk = 1
}
```